pdfgrep How to locate the pages that contain multiple strings and print the page numbers?
In a pdf file, there are some pages that contain both string1 and string2. I would like to locate those pages and print the page numbers.

What have you tried and what isn't working? What you are asking for is covered in the man page for pdfgrep.

You could use pdfgrep -p to get a report of the number of matches on each page.
Get that report for both words separately and then join them on the page number.
Here using mlr to do the joining as join expects records to be sorted on the join key lexically. That also allows us to get pretty output formatting. Here assuming a shell with support for ksh-style process substitution such as zsh or bash. rc, es, yash or fish have equivalent features with a different syntax.
$ mlr --icsv --opprint --implicit-csv-header --ifs : \
    join -j 1 --lp l -f <(pdfgrep -Fp -- "$first" "$file") then \
    rename 1,page,l2,first,2,second <(pdfgrep -Fp -- "$second" "$file")
page first second
4    9     3
5    22    6
6    7     1
7    18    4
9    13    1
10   12    4
11   12    10
12   15    7
13   8     3
14   9     7
15   13    4
16   6     2

If you only care about the page numbers:
mlr --csv --fs : -N join -j 1 --lp l \
  -f <(pdfgrep -Fp -- "$first" "$file") then \
  cut -f 1 <(pdfgrep -Fp -- "$second" "$file")

Same with join:
join -t: -o0 <(pdfgrep -Fp -- "$first"  "$file" | sort -t: -k1,1) \
             <(pdfgrep -Fp -- "$second" "$file" | sort -t: -k1,1) |
  sort -n

Or comm:
comm -12 <(pdfgrep -Fp -- "$first"  "$file" | cut -d: -f1 | sort) \
         <(pdfgrep -Fp -- "$second" "$file" | cut -d: -f1 | sort) |
  sort -n


This is likely the only viable solution, since string1 and string2 aren't specified as being on the same line of text (only on the same page), and even in Perl-compatible mode pdfgrep doesn't appear to offer any sort of multiline mode. So, doing it in one command using a (string1.*string2|string2.*string1) style expression is out, alas, as that'll miss any pages where the two strings are separated by one or more newlines.

@FeRD, actually, using perl regexps seems to work just fine. See the other answer I just added.

In perl mode, you can set the s flag with (?s) so . also matches on newline and search for both strings using look ahead operators from the start of the page. Use -p to get a number of matches per page (which here can at most be 1) and cut it away:
pdfgrep -pP '(?s)\A(?=.*string1)(?=.*string2)' file.pdf | cut -d: -f1

To do that for a number of arbitrary strings:
#! /bin/sh -
# Usage: that-script <file> <string1> [<string2>...]
file=$1; shift
pdfgrep -pP -- "(?s)\A$(
  printf '(?=.*\\Q%s\\E)' "$@")" "$file" | cut -d: -f1

Well, technically, that's not any arbitrary string, as it would fail for those containing \E (as we surround the string with \Q...\E to quote the regex operators in there). For really arbitrary strings, we could do:
#! /bin/zsh -
# Usage: that-script <file> <string1> [<string2>...]
file=$1; shift
look_aheads=( '(?=.*\Q'${^@//'\E'/'\E\\E\Q'}'\E)' )
pdfgrep -pP -- "(?s)\A${(j[])look_aheads}" "$file" | cut -d: -f1

As for limiting the number of lines between the two strings, you could do:
pdfgrep -pP 'string1(.*\n){0,10}string2|string2(.*\n){0,10}string1' file.pdf | cut -d: -f1

Here allowing up to 10 line delimiters between the two strings on a given page.
Or for any number of arbitrary strings to be found in no more than a given number of consecutive lines:
#! /bin/zsh -
# Usage: that-script <file> <max-lines> <string1> [<string2>...]
file=$1 n=$(( ${2//[^0-9]} - 1 )); shift 2
quoted_strings=( '\Q'${^@//'\E'/'\E\\E\Q'}'\E' )
look_aheads=( "(?=(?:.*\n){0,$n}.*"$^quoted_strings')' )
any_string=( "(?=${(j[|])quoted_strings})" )
pdfgrep -pP -- "$any_string${(j[])look_aheads}" "$file" | cut -d: -f1

For instance, if called as that-script file.pdf 5 foo bar '\END/', that would run:
pdfgrep -pP -- '(?=\Qfoo\E|\Qbar\E|\Q\E\\E\QND/\E)(?=(?:.*\n){0,4}.*\Qfoo\E)(?=(?:.*\n){0,4}.*\Qbar\E)(?=(?:.*\n){0,4}.*\Q\E\\E\QND/\E)' file.pdf | cut -d: -f1


Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. Is it possible to put a limit on the number of lines between the two strings, since there is typically a limit of line number on a single page? And what if I need to search 3 strings? Thanks again in advance!

@Glenn, see edit.

Fantastic! Thanks again!

IS this actually limited to a given page, though, using this method? By which I mean, say you set up a search for two strings with <max-lines> set to 10. Now, you're searching a document where <string1> appears on page 4, <string2> appears on page 5, and page 4 only has 5 lines, total, on it. Will the lookahead be prevented from going past the end of page 4 and finding <string2> even though it's not on the same page as <string1>?

@FeRD, this gives a list of pages where all the strings are found with 10 lines of each other. The regex in pdfgrep matches on the contents of a single page at a time, it can't match across pages.
